# Button next to text with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do something really simple : have some text and a group of buttons (using the `btn-group` class) next to it:

```
Make your choice : BUTTON
```

Here is the code I use :

```
<div>
    <p>Make your choice :</p>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Button <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" id="btn1">Select 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btn2">Select 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btn3">Select 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code produces something like:

```
Make your choice :
BUTTON
```

I'm looking for a **Bootstrap** solution to have the text and the button on the same line. I don't want to create my own styles, I'd like to achieve this using existing Bootstrap classes/components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the `<p></p>` :

```
<div>
Make your choice :

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Button <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="btn1">Select 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="btn2">Select 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="btn3">Select 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it's that easy.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is way after the fact (but may be useful for others), and doesn't really use the bootstrap classes 'properly' but I wanted some text next to buttons but also aligned properly with them: simply making the text inline didn't result in it being vertically aligned with the buttons. Turns out you can just abuse the `btn` class:

```
<div class="btn">
    Actions: 
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" >Back To Client</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` element has `display:block` as default, that's why u're seeing button below it. You could make it inline (or inline-block). i.e. 
http://jsfiddle.net/2fTmb/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This also solves the problem, but Céline's answer is cleaner as I don't need to add some extra style. And I don't think removing <p> doesn't make me lose anything. If you think it does, please tell me !

Comment: Wrapping it on an element (p, or span in your case would be better because of it's inline display as default) allows you to have zero hassle in the case you want to apply some style to it :)

Comment: Yeah I see. I'll "span" it then ! :) Thanks !